# Toolbar in fragments onclick listeners

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-toolbar

I am using a toolbar in my main activity as follows:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/mainToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/navBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_dehaze_black_24dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"

                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
                android:text="Shop"
                android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"

                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
                android:text="Lyft"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:textColor="#E91E63"
                android:textSize="26sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/searchBTn"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp" />




        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and I have put an onclick method on my mainactivty as follows:

```
ImageView searchBTn=findViewById(R.id.searchBTn);
    searchBTn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent sendtoSearch=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Search.class);
            startActivity(sendtoSearch);
        }
    });
```

Now I Have added fragments to my main activity. But I have made sure the toolbar of the mainactivty is always visible on the fragments. Now the issue I face is when ever I click on any of the toolbar image views or buttons there is no response. I have tried using static methods yet I was unable to find a solution. I know if we create a menu file it would be easier to implement but is there any other way to do this without making changes to my mainactivty toolbar

Comment: If the `Toolbar` works without a `Fragment`, then it sounds like it's being overlapped by the `Fragment`'s `View`. Please [edit] your question to add the `Activity`'s layout, and you show how you're adding the `Fragment`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your `Toolbar` from your `Fragment` with this code:

```
final AppCompatActivity act = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
if (act.getSupportActionBar() != null) {
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) act.getSupportActionBar().getCustomView();
}
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31183141/10089811).

Answer (score 0):

You hold your views inside Toolbar. The better approach is to use constraint layout and place your views at the top of toolbar. It's looks like what you cannot click on your button because toolbar overlap your views.

Try:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/mainToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="51dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"/>

            <LinearLayout
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/mainToolbar"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/mainToolbar"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/navBtn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_dehaze_black_24dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
                    android:text="Shop"
                    android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="26sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
                    android:text="Lyft"
                    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                    android:textColor="#E91E63"
                    android:textSize="26sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/searchBTn"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```